# Send Calendar Event via Chat (XMPP) Android

Tags: android, calendar, xmpp, chat

I'm just getting up to speed on Android, and I want to send calendar event to others from mobile. Same as whatsapp sending contacts. For sending Contact in chat (**XMPP**) I've used `vCard`. So for sending calendar event in chat what should I use?

I have searched a lot. But can't find something fruitful.

Please suggest the library or code snippet for sending calendar event in `XMPP`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refer to [iCal Import Export](https://github.com/dschuermann/ical-import-export) allows you to import `iCalender` files to your calender without using google synchronization services.

Using this you can import all calendar events to `iCalendar` files and also export those events back to calendar. Using [Calendar Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) you can fetch all calendar data, but requires android **API level 14** or above while using [iCal Import Export](https://github.com/dschuermann/ical-import-export) you can fetch all calendar data for **lower API levels** too.

Answer (score 1):

manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
```

Code:

```
Cursor cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars"), new String[]{ "_id",  "displayname" }, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
String[] CalNames = new String[cursor.getCount()];
int[] CalIds = new int[cursor.getCount()];
for (int i = 0; i < CalNames.length; i++) {
    CalIds[i] = cursor.getInt(0);
    CalNames[i] = cursor.getString(1);
    cursor.moveToNext();
}
cursor.close();
```

Fetching all events, and particular event is done by specifying range

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase() + "/instances/when").buildUpon();
        long now = new Date().getTime();
        ContentUris.appendId(builder, now - DateUtils.MILLIS_PER_DAY*10000);
        ContentUris.appendId(builder, now + DateUtils.MILLIS_PER_DAY * 10000);
```

and then let's say you wish to log events ID from calendar with ID = 1

```
Cursor eventCursor = contentResolver.query(builder.build(),
                new String[] { "event_id"}, "Calendars._id=" + 1,
                null, "startDay ASC, startMinute ASC"); 
        // For a full list of available columns see http://tinyurl.com/yfbg76w
        while (eventCursor.moveToNext()) {
            String uid2 = eventCursor.getString(0);
            Log.v("eventID : ", uid2);

        }
```

Now display this event in Listview select one of this for send as a text messsage and on receiver side :

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();              
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
intent.putExtra("title", HERE MSG WHICH YOU RECEIVE);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: where is getCalendarUriBase() defined?

Comment: "content://calendar/calendars"

Comment: MILLIS_PER_DAY is not available with ANDROID.

Comment: long days = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(milliseconds);

Answer (score 0):

There is no library AFAIK and it's really just a matter of retrieving the calender event and transforming it's data into XML. Unfortunately there is also no XEP on how calendar events should be represented in XMPP/XML so you have to come up with your own representation.

Answer (score 0):

[iCalendar/vCalendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) is the calendar file format similar to vCard

Comment: From where I can download it?

Comment: Did you see RFC links on the right-top of Wikipedia article?

Comment: Yes, RFC 5545 in Standards.

Answer (score 0):

You can add new field in vcard that save calender info example

```
VCard vCard = new VCard();
vCard.setField("calender","calender info");
```

calender info should be a sting, it can be a json format string.

user who receives it can load your vcard and use method

```
vCard.load(connection, Jid);
String string=vCard.getField("calender");
```

Answer (score -3):

You really don't need any specific library for that purpose.
You can check out [Calendar Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html)
They have an awesome example on it too!

Be sure to use these permissions in your manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
```

And if you wish to send contacts then check this out [Android: How to import contact from phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444503/android-how-to-import-contact-from-phone)

Vote this up if it helped you! I really need it. :)

Comment: I don't want to import calendar events only. I want to import calendar event and send it via sms.As vCard is used for sending contact. :)

Comment: what you could do is get the vCard and parse its details. After that use sms provider to send the text message.

Comment: I want to send calendar event not the contact. For sending contact I used vCard. For calendar event sending which library should I use?

Comment: Use this. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html